# Выбрать из таблицы все значения по одному разу (без повторов)

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим есть такая таблица:

```
id|name|number
1 |Igor|89172281212
2 |Petr|89274554545
3 |Andr|89172281212
```

Подскажите, как составить sql-код, который выведет 1 и 2 строчку, а 3 не надо, т.к. их телефоны (с 1м) одинаковые.

Comment: как вариант - `group by number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно явно исключить лишние записи. Только надо определится по какому конкретно условию исключать. Вернее какая из записей с данным телефоном может быть более интересна. Например

```
select * from Table as A
 where not exists(select 1
                    from Table as B
                   where B.number=A.number and B.id<A.id)
```

В данном случае будут выбраны записи с данным телефонным номером у которых минимальный Id. Так как условие выборки звучит как "Выбери все записи для которых не существует записей с тем же номером но с ID меньше, чем у найденной"

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сгруппировать выдачу по какому либо параметру (number) и указать что делать с остальными колонками (id, name) при группировке (min max count avg sum и т.п.)

Comment: здесь mysql, а значит агрегатные функции не нужны, достаточно просто `select id, name... group by number`. Для не-mysql такой подход не верен - придется использовать агрегатные функции, а значит данные могут принадлежать разным людям. Поэтому через подзапрос лучше делать

Comment: @BOPOH Указать что делать с остальными колонками в любом случае надо, и решать это автору.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `number` HAVING count(*)>1. Пробовал так, но в таком случае выдает только записи, где есть повторы

Comment: @user2244523 А зачем вам `HAVING count(*)>1` и что он по-вашему делает?

Comment: Считает количество повторений

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с подзапросом (по номеру берём минимальный id и потом по выбранным id соотв. записи):

```
select T.*
from TableName T
    join (
        select min(id) as id
        from TableName
        group by number
    ) T2 on T2.id = T.id
```

Comment: здесь `number` в select'е не сильно-то и нужен, мы же его нигде не используем больше

Comment: @BOPOH, верно, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Упрощаю

```
select * from t 
where id in(
select min(id) from t
group by number)
```